# How is mobile communication(between pilot and ATC ) made possible from airplanes?

Tags: communication, radio

I have heard that communication using mobile phones begins to degrade when used on a vehicle moving at speeds above 200 km/hr due to [doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) as described [here](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/art_sklar6_mitigating/elementLinks/art_sklar6_mitigating.pdf) (p-22). How is this limitation overcome in airplanes. What is the specific technology used to overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

[ATC use Amplitude Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airband#Modulation) (AM) which is less susceptible to doppler effects due to relative motion at typical aircraft speeds.

Comment: I wonder how much of a problem doppler would be using voice FM? Apart from the brief moment of passing overhead I thought the doppler change would have been pretty gradual and probably much less than normal carrier drift the PLL has to deal with. This is not a criticism of your answer because I'm not sure but an explanation in that area would be a great addition.

Comment: The moment of passing by is when the shift passes through zero, but the rate of change is fairly consistent... someone flying right at the tower then pulling immelan turn might be a bit more interesting, but still not an issue for the voice technologies in use.  As voice FM is effectively AC coupled, a slight time-varying DC component in the channel is not a big issue.  But for single sideband voice or on-off-keyed morse code through an amateur radio satellite, it is an issue and the ground stations have to be set up to track the frequency shift.

Answer (score 2):

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/in-flight-mobile-phone-services1.htm

Basically an extra "cell" is created on the plane, and because the base station is moving at the same speed as the mobile phone, there is no doppler effect. Backhaul is done over satellite, which is perpendicular to the plane's direction of travel and therefore does not suffer from doppler either.

Comment: How does the pilot communicate with the air traffic control when the plane is travelling at 500 km/hr

Comment: This answer is not related to pilot <-> ATC communication

Comment: The original question's first line included "communication using mobile phones" and the title was later edited to specify ATC.